# Undefined expectation for a random variable

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am having a bit of trouble with the calculation of an expectation. Solving using the distribution function I get density $2$ but this "breaks" the expectation for $\frac{Z}{1-Z}$ and I get undefined. What am I doing wrong?

~

Let $X$ be random variable $\in U(0,1)$. Let $Z = min(X, 1-X)$. Find $EZ$ and $E(\frac{Z}{1-Z})$

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: Shouldn't $Y$ appear somewhere? It seems like it's missing...

Comment: $Y$ is used for another sub-problem. I should not have included it, my bad

Comment: How did you find the density of $Z$?

Comment: First, I have calculated the distribution function of $Z$. Then, I have differentiated the function and I have found the density.

Comment: Just use $E(f(x)) = \int f(t) p(t) dt$ in the case of an absolutely continuous random variable.

Comment: @fmi21 It would be a good idea to show your calculations so that we might help figure out why you get something undefined.

Comment: "Let $X$ be independent random variable." Independent of what? What is the distribution of $X$?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio uniform distribution - I'm adding this, sorry!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess as to what you've done wrong is that the density of $Z$ isn't $$p_Z(z) = 2$$ but rather $$p_Z(z) = \begin{cases}2 & \text{if} \ 0 \le z \le 1/2 \\ 0 & \text{else} \end{cases}.$$ Hence, the expectations are $$\mathbb{E}[Z] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}zp_Z(z)\,dz = \int_{0}^{1/2}2z\,dz$$ and $$\mathbb{E}\left[\dfrac{Z}{1-Z}\right] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\dfrac{z}{1-z}p_Z(z)\,dz = \int_{0}^{1/2}\dfrac{2z}{1-z}z\,dz,$$ both of which are well-defined and finite due to the bounds of the integral.